# How to increment a variable value in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to increment a number each time a sub is executed in VBScript. For example:

```vb
sub increment()
    X=200
end sub
```

After I use the value of `X` (200) for the first time when the sub is executed, the value is not valid next the time sub is executed. I need to use x=201 next time when the sub is executed. How do I set X=201, X=202, X=203 and so on every time the sub is executed?

Comment: Put `dim x` before the sub?

Answer (score 2):

As @GSerg suggests, declare the X variable outside the Sub:

```
' Declare and Initalize X
Dim X
X = 200

Sub Increment()
    X = X + 1
End Sub
```

The scope of `X` in your question is limited to the procedure it is used in since it is not declared anywhere. You want to declare your variable at the module level. Take a look at this article from Microsoft regarding variable scope, it has a very similar example: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications). Even though it is for VBA, it applies to VBScript also.

Another approach that uses the same concept is to make `Increment` a Function:

```
Function Increment(p_iValue)
    Increment = p_iValue + 1
End Function
```

This would be the equivalent code:

```
' Declare and Initalize X
Dim X
X = 200

' Do this whenever you need a new value for X
X = Increment(X)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am really new to VBScript. How this code increases the value of X each time  sub is executed? I will give another try to explain my problem clearly. I need to set the value of X from 200 to 201, 201 to 202, 202 to 203,, and son on. Because the field in my application will not accept the previous value, every time it needs a new number. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: X is incremented (because of the `X = X + 1` line) every time `Increment` is called. X is initialized at 200 (`X = 200` line). If you post your entire script perhaps we can better help you but this code shows you how to declared a variable that will be reused in `Increment` sub.